# Sockets con NestJs y mongoose

Tags: mongoose, websocket, nestjs

Tengo una duda, soy algo nuevo en NestJs y estoy intentando usar **sockets**
Intente hacer un archivo .gateway y probar mi socket en la siguiente página :
https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/v1/#
No me logré conectar, adjunto mi archivo .gateway

```js
import {
  ConnectedSocket,
  MessageBody,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  OnGatewayInit,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { NestGateway } from '@nestjs/websockets/interfaces/nest-gateway.interface';
import { Bind } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AvisosService } from './avisos.service'
import { CreateAvisoDto } from './dto/create-aviso.dto';

@WebSocketGateway(4200)
export class NotificationGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection  {

  constructor(private avisoService: AvisosService) { }

  afterInit(server: any) {
    console.log(`Ìnitialized! ${server}`);
  }

  handleConnection(socket: any) {
    console.log('Connect', socket);
    process.nextTick(async () => {
      socket.emit('allAvisos', await this.avisoService.getAvisoReciente());
    });
  }

  handleDisconnect(socket: any) {
    console.log(`Client disconnect ${socket}`);
  }

  @Bind(MessageBody(), ConnectedSocket())
  @SubscribeMessage('notification')
  async handleNewNotification(sender: any) {
    await this.avisoService.getAvisoReciente();
    console.log(sender)
  }

}
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando mongoose.

Espero alguien pueda apoyarme, muchas gracias!

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/adapter#extend-socketio https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting#websockets Espero que pronto esperes respuesta amigo, porque necesitamos terminarlo, saludos a la familia!

Comment: Trata de especificar con cors el sitio en el que estas intentando probarlo.
Espero pueda funcionarte...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058598/nextjs-cors-issue